# JSON Parsing for Android

Tags: android, json, parsing

Let us suppose that we have the following JSON format which is a bit complicated.

```
items: [
{
  kind: "customsearch#result",
  title: "Flower - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia",
  htmlTitle: "<b>Flower</b> - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia",
  link:    
  "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a5/Flower_poster_2.jpg",
  displayLink: "en.wikipedia.org",
  snippet: "Flower - Wikipedia, the free",
  htmlSnippet: "<b>Flower</b> - Wikipedia, the free",
  mime: "image/jpeg",

  image: {
   contextLink: "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flower",
   height: 5932,
   width: 4462,
   byteSize: 4487679,
   thumbnailLink: "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?   
   q=tbn:ANd9GcQdv1k3rb2HdBbQy9rEt_LX-PNnOd9uZ-O0PExeAJQfgoPxUna6pzS6ivfU",
   thumbnailHeight: 150,
   thumbnailWidth: 113
  }

 }
]
```

I also have the following simple class.

```
public class WebImage {

private String mUrl;
private String mThumbnailUrl;

public WebImage(String url, String thumbnailUrl) {
    mUrl = url;
    mThumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return mUrl;
}

public String getThumbnailUrl() {
    return mThumbnailUrl;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return mUrl + " | " + mThumbnailUrl;
 }
}
```

I am interested in the "items" JSON array. Every item in the array contains an image "link" and an "image" JSON object with the "thumbnailLink".

```
private static List<WebImage> parseJsonResponse(String jsonResponse) throws 
JSONException {

    List<WebImage> webImages = new ArrayList<WebImage>();

    // TODO: perform the parsing.



    return webImages;
 }
```

How should I read  the objects? I am a bit confused with that one.

Thank you,

Theo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`items` is `JSONArray` of `JSONObject` and every JSONObject contain `image` JSONObject.  Get both `link` and `thumbnailLink`  as:

```
JSONArray array =new JSONArray(jsonResponse);
 List<WebImage> webImages = new ArrayList<WebImage>();
for(int n = 0; n < array.length(); n++)
{
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(n);
    // get link from object
    String strLink= object.optString("link");
    // get image JSONObject
    JSONObject objectInner = object.getJSONObject("image");
    // get thumbnailLink from objectInner
    String strthumbnailLink= object.optString("thumbnailLink");
    WebImage objWebImage=new WebImage(strLink,strthumbnailLink);

   // add objWebImage to ArrayList
    webImages.add(objWebImage);

}
```